# How to set multiple spark configurations for same spark job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am dealing with a weird situation , where I have small tables and big tables to process using spark and it must be a single spark job.

To achieve best performance targets, I need to set a property called

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 12 for small tables and
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 500 for bigger tables
```

I want to know how can I change these properties dynamically in spark ?
Can I have multiple configuration files and call it within the program ?

Answer (score 0):

[apache-spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html) describes this property:

> spark.sql.shuffle.partitions  200 Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations.

according to above description you need just to load your data to rdds and when you want to apply the join or aggregation on them you can change partition numbers using repartition method. 
As mentioned in documentation the default value is 200 then you need one increasing and one decreasing in partition numbers. Then you should use repartition and coalesce method. Repartition is useful for both decreasing and increasing but in decreasing is has a shuffle overhead but coalesce does not have this overhead and is more optimized than repartition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the tables in parquet files for instance, you could read files in advance and know if is small table or big table and change the value of your shuffle partitions.

```
val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
val shuffle12 = "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 12"
val shuffle500= "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 500"
val total = hdfs.getContentSummary(new Path(pathTable)).getLength
if (total < x) shuffle12 else shuffle500
```